# Add button to infoWindow

Tags: google-maps, button, google-maps-api-3, kml, infowindow

I am using geoxml inn order to parse kml file containing number of points. Each marker has an info window with some information. Now what I would like is to add a button to each info window and onclick I would be able to display the information in that particular infowindow in a textbox.

Now my question is how am I able to add such button that on click I will get the info of the infowindow?

The following is an image of an infowindow:

[image]

And this is the code i have done so far:

```
      function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google

.maps.LatLng(35.898737028438, 14.5133403246687),
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

        }


        function displayKml() {
            initialize();

            parser = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                infoWindow: infowindow,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
                zoom: true,
                markerOptions: { optimized: false }
             });
            parser.parse("Uploads/" + document.getElementById('<%= text2.ClientID %>').value);

        }
```

The kml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>route</name>
    <Placemark>
      <name>188</name>
      <description>museum</description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>14.5104009086433,35.8994513796904</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>196</name>
      <description>museum</description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>14.5105859971021,35.8991906966932</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>349</name>
      <description>museum</description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>14.5126379237713,35.8969782492105</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: geoxml3 is very flexible, there are a few ways to do this, one of which is adding that HTML to your KML (using a javascript function from the page in the onclick).  Another is overriding the createMarker function.  What does your KML look like? Is this the last thing you need to add (at least to the mapping code)? Is this only for markers or also for polylines/polygons?

Comment: Yes practically it is almost the last thing to the mapping code. I have updated the question with the kml file. Only for markers I am intending to do it. @geocodezip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: Override the createMarker function:

```
function displayKml() {
    geo = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        zoom: true,
        singleInfoWindow: true,
        infoWindow: infowindow,
        createMarker: createMarker 
    });
    geo.parse(document.getElementById('kmlFile').value);
}

function createMarker(placemark, doc) {
  // create a Marker to the map from a placemark KML object

    // Load basic marker properties
    var markerOptions = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(placemark.Point.coordinates[0].lat, placemark.Point.coordinates[0].lng),
      title:    placemark.name,
      zIndex:   Math.round(placemark.Point.coordinates[0].lat * -100000)<<5,
      icon:     placemark.style.icon,
      shadow:   placemark.style.shadow 
    };

    // Create the marker on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    if (!!doc) {
      // doc.markers.push(marker);
    }

    // Set up and create the infowindow
    var infoWindowOptions = {
      content: '<div class="geoxml3_infowindow"><h3>' + placemark.name + 
               '</h3><div>' + placemark.description + '</div>'+
               '<input type="button" onclick="displayInfo(\''+placemark.name+'\',\''+placemark.description+'\');" value="populate div"></input>',
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2)
    };
    infowindow.setOptions(infoWindowOptions);
    marker.infoWindowOptions = infoWindowOptions;
    marker.infoWindow = infowindow;
    // Infowindow-opening event handler
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      this.infoWindow.close();
      marker.infoWindow.setOptions(this.infoWindowOptions);
      this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this);
    });
    placemark.marker = marker;
    return marker;
}
```

Add a function to display the data in an external div:

```
function displayInfo(name,description){
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = name+"<br>"+description;
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_simpleMap_geoxml3_button.html)

Comment: Thanks very much I really appreciated your help. It works brilliantly. Thanks for all your help in all my posts and queries. :)

Comment: The best thanks would be to go back and accept answers to any of your previous questions that helped along the way (if the were useful).